# How to disable or hide localization in Number keyboard type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboardtype

In my iOS app, when the user click on a `UITextfield` I need to change the keyboard view to the numeric view automatically. I write below code and it is working fine.

```
UITextField *txtfield  = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
txtfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

My app supports localization. I added 4 keyboards on the device like English, Spanish, Hindi, Emoji. I want disable or hide localization in number keyboard type. Please see attached image. I have highlighted in red box.

[image]

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Applies for iOS 10 or later)

**Swift**

Use  `.asciiCapableNumberPad` for Xcode 8.3/Swift 3.1 for only numbers

```
txtField.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad
```

**Objective-C**

```
txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapableNumberPad
```

Comment: This doesn't allows a decimal value to be entered

Comment: Thats what OP asked

Answer (score 3):

@Jack answer is correct but if you need to support iDevices with iOS9 and below, you need to put a check like this:

```
if (IS_OS_10_OR_LATER) {
  txtfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapableNumberPad;
}
else {
  txtfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
}
```

If not, the users will see a **Default** keyboard type if their iDevice is still on iOS9 and below.